# Can a session carry long text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

In ASP.NET C# `Session["transfer_item_1"]` can this function carry a very long text of 1Mn chars? or do it have any limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that but it is not recommended neither serves the purpose. It degrades server performance.

Check this for your complete options.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using SQL server to hold your session, the limit of your session in the server varies according to the available memory you have available.

You may successfully store it when in local development machine, but may get out of memory errors when trying it on the production server.

Using sql server may solve your needs, but performance is terrible and not a good idea.

If it's a same object that many users will be accessing and sharing, you may try looking into storing it in the Cache.

Answer (score 0):

A session is typically stored in memory (although it can be configured to be stored in sql server etc) so yes it has limits but 1mn characters will probably be less than 5mb of data.

Although if this data will be created per request and is unique per user, you might run out of memory depending on the number of hits you get on your application.

If this information is typically used by all requests you might consider using the Cache object or the Application object.